# Divide Array to something like Masonry Grid

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

## What I need to help with:

1. I need to create a function **toColumns** that will be able to
   divide photos Array to (chunks) Array according to the example below.
2. Another function **fromColumns** as a reverse function.

It will remind the Masonry Grid for photos.

### Example:

1. toColumns([1, 2, 3, 4], 3) -> [[4, 1], [3], [2]]
2. toColumns([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) -> [[4, 2], [3, 1]]
3. toColumns([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) -> [[4, 3, 2, 1]]
4. toColumns([1, 2, 3, 4], 5) -> [[4], [3], [2], [1]] - if we do not have enough photos

**Why 4 with 1?** - Graphically (3 columns)

```
|-----------|
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
|-----------|
| 1 |   |   |
|-----------|
```

**Why 4 with 2 and 3 with 1?** - Graphically (2 columns)

```
---------
| 4 | 3 |
---------
| 2 | 1 |
---------
```

#### Code: (https://jsfiddle.net/f3r2r28s/)

```
const photos = [{
  id: 1,
  height: '50px',
  photo: 'A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  height: '100px',
  photo: 'B'
}, {
  id: 3,
  height: '150px',
  photo: 'C'
}, {
  id: 4,
  height: '200px',
  photo: 'D'
}];

let response = [];

const toColumns = (photos, columns) => {
  /*
    Response:
        response = [
          [
            {
              id: 4,
              photo: 'D',
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              photo: 'A',
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              id: 3,
              photo: 'C',
            },
          ],
          [
            {
              id: 2,
              photo: 'B',
            },
          ],
      ];
  */
};

toColumns(photos, 3);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you deal with remainder photos when the number is not divisible between the number of columns?

Comment: Add some more rules telling how it should be splitted into columns. I have no idea why `1` is with `4` in first example.

Comment: @Altaula Wow, your attitude is just great. Maybe you should start to read what StackOverflow is and what it is not. Hint: It is not a website where people create code for free while being insulted.

Comment: @str dude but I need serious help... and these people give me a "-" without reason

Comment: @Altaula "-1" means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It is slightly unclear and does not show any research effort.

Comment: @str - I think my question makes sense. Stack Overflow always helped me solve my problem. And I changed the original question several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this is what you want

```
const toColumns = (photos, columns) => {
    photos = photos.reverse()
    let response = []
    for(let i = 0, l = photos.length; i < l; i++){
        let j = i % columns
        response[j] = response[j] || []
        response[j].push(photos[i])
    }
    return response
}
const fromColumns = (columns) => {
    let result = []
    let i = j = 0, l = columns.length
    while (1){
        if(!columns[i][j]) break
        result.push(columns[i][j])
        if(++i >= l){
            i = 0
            j++
        }
    }
    return result.reverse()
}
let photos = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(toColumns(photos, 3)) // [ [ 4, 1 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ] ]
console.log(toColumns(photos, 2)) // [ [ 4, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ] ]
console.log(toColumns(photos, 1)) // [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ]
console.log(toColumns(photos, 5)) // [ [ 4 ], [ 3 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
console.log(fromColumns(toColumns(photos, 2))) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```